# Filedialog and Tkinter creating blank lines on terminal

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I've had this weird problem with my application where it periodically creates 2 blank lines. I've narrowed the problem down to the filedialog.askdirectory() and filedialog.askopenfilename() functions from Tkinter. I was wondering if anybody knows why these functions are causing my program to create 2 blank lines when they're called and then creates another 2 blank lines every 15~30 seconds. I'm just trying to open windows explorer so the user can choose where the program will import/export files.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import tkinter 
from  tkinter import filedialog
export_file_path = ""

#Export path for output file
def export_path():

    global export_file_path

    is_empty = filedialog.askdirectory()

    if is_empty != '':

        export_file_path = is_empty.replace('/', '\\') 

export_path()
print(export_file_path)
```

Here's what my terminal looks like when the button is clicked to call this function.
[image]

Comment: Are you sure that is where the problem is coming from? `filedialog.askdirectory` shouldn't print anything on the terminal. Try creating a minimal working example that we can copy/paste and try it for our selves. Also please check that you don't any `print` statements that can cause the problem.

Comment: @TheLizzard I've changed the export_path() function to only include a print statement and the blank lines went away.  I even tried using only filedialog.askdirectory in the export_path() function and the 2 blank lines came back. Also, I've checked the other print statements and I don't see anything that could be causing this. Let me try getting a working example for you.

Comment: @TheLizzard I updated the code to include a working example. Using this example on VS code, I'm still seeing 2 blanks lines when filedialog.askdirectory() opens file explorer.

Comment: I only see the folder that I've selected or a blank line if I clicked `Cancel` when using IDLE. When I use CMD to run it and cancel the filedialog, I get an empty line for the `print(export_file_path)` and another one that CMD automatically adds when the program terminates. Try changing `print(export_file_path)` to `print(repr(export_file_path))`. Also it might just be a visual studio bug.

Comment: @TheLizzard I believe you're right about the bug with Visual Studio because I'm not seeing these blank lines when running it through CMD. I appreciate your help on this.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is most likely a bug within Visual Studio. Running this same code through CMD doesn't produce any blank lines.